# SES - how to set HeadersInDeliveryNotificationsEnabled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

We want to check that all mails are correctly delivered using Email header and SNS + SES Notification, but header is not included in the notification published to SNS.

I found `HeadersinDeliveryNotificationsEnabled` flag in `get-identity-noticiation-attributes`, but there are no way to set it.

How can I set it?

```
$ aws ses get-identity-notification-attributes --region us-west-2 --identities 'info@example.com'
{
"NotificationAttributes": {
    "info@example.com": {
        "BounceTopic": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:009393527413:info_example_com-Bounce",
        "HeadersInBounceNotificationsEnabled": false,
        "DeliveryTopic": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:009393527413:info_example_com-Delivery",
        "HeadersInDeliveryNotificationsEnabled": false,
        "ComplaintTopic": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:009393527413:info_example_com-Complaint",
        "HeadersInComplaintNotificationsEnabled": false,
        "ForwardingEnabled": true
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the messageId value for this.

When you send message via SES it gives back a message id that is unique for each send. You will need to persist that somewhere

Now when SES sends a bounce or a delivery notification it sends that message id back in the notification payload. You will have to read that and correlate with the previously persisted messageId